# Makefile considering target remade without running any rules

Tags: makefile

I was answering another question --
 [Dependency ordering error for multi-job make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393688/dependency-ordering-error-for-multi-job-make/44395247?noredirect=1#comment75982380_44395247) on SO, and I posted the following makefile.  The OP replied back saying if `-j` wasn't specified on the command line, it wouldn't build the `dir1/out/file.bar` target...   Perplexed, I verified that it works with `-j2` but not with `-j1`.   I've looked it over, and I'm not seeing what I missed.   I thought I'd post it here in case someone knows, as I'm very curious...

```
$(shell mkdir dir1 >& /dev/null; touch dir1/file.foo; \
        mkdir dir2 >& /dev/null; touch dir2/file.foo)


OUTDIRS = dir1/out dir2/out
OUTPUTS = dir1/out/file.bar dir2/out/file.bar

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

$(OUTPUTS) : | $(OUTDIRS)

$(OUTDIRS) :
        @echo "making $@"
        sleep 1
        mkdir -p $@
        @echo "done making $@"


%.bar : ../%.foo
        @echo "copying $< to $@"
        @cp $< $@

all : outputs
        @echo "done $@"

outputs : $(OUTPUTS)
        @echo "created all output files"

clean :
        @rm -rf dir1 dir2
```

I am running make 3.81, and OP was using 3.82.   I tried running with `make -d -j1 -r`, and I get the following snippet:

```
     Finished prerequisites of target file `dir1/out/file.bar'.
    Must remake target `dir1/out/file.bar'.
    Successfully remade target file `dir1/out/file.bar'.
    Considering target file `dir2/out/file.bar'.
     File `dir2/out/file.bar' does not exist.
      Considering target file `dir2/out/../file.foo'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file `dir2/out/../file.foo'.
      No need to remake target `dir2/out/../file.foo'.
      Pruning file `dir1/out'.
      Pruning file `dir2/out'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `dir2/out/file.bar'.
    Must remake target `dir2/out/file.bar'.
copying dir2/out/../file.foo to dir2/out/file.bar
    Successfully remade target file `dir2/out/file.bar'.
```

It seems to think it remade dir1/out/file.bar, but it didn't run any targets/recipes to do so...   I'm wondering what I missed...

Comment: I suspect this is a known bug.

Comment: Having a similar issue, I agree a bug. How to work around?

Comment: I worked around by adding a dummy file that depends on the missing file, for example:

obj/makebug: obj/missingfile
<tab>@touch obj/makebug

Comment: There are two rules to make the ".bar" files. Try putting a print under the $(OUTPUTS) rule and see if it's being called. If so, I'd delete that and move the directory dependency onto the individual .bar rules. Let me know if that is or isn't it, I'm curious.